# Amazon SNS Filter control and access

Tags: amazon-sns

Looking to setup a aws SNS topic - I intend to subscribe a third party to this topic and I’m hoping that I can use its message filtering to ensure said third party only gets the messages they need.

Is that possible? Since I control the SNS topic I’m hoping I can also control who gets to see what but the docs are not super clear.

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon SNS Message Filtering - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html):

> By default, an Amazon SNS topic subscriber receives every message published to the topic. To receive a subset of the messages, a subscriber must assign a **filter policy** to the topic subscription.
>
> A filter policy is a simple JSON object containing attributes that define which messages the subscriber receives. When you publish a message to a topic, Amazon SNS compares the message attributes to the attributes in the filter policy for each of the topic's subscriptions. If any of the attributes match, Amazon SNS sends the message to the subscriber. Otherwise, Amazon SNS skips the subscriber without sending the message. If a subscription doesn't have a filter policy, the subscription receives every message published to its topic.

Comment: Right but if you as the publisher are in charge of the SNS topic which also means you control the subscribers it’s not possible for the subscribers themselves to remove the policy? Or is it?

Comment: Correct. Subscribers would have no access to SNS. Your application would be responsible for adding Subscribers to a Topic. When doing so, the application could add a relevant filter, or it can be added/changed later.